# Is there any way to schedule a php script run or a mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

is there any way to schedule a php script or a mysql query to run automatically for example every day at 00.00??

I would like to automatically run some queries on a mysql database, is it possible to do it with mysql or php?

Comment: Your search keyword is "cron job".

Comment: search for cronjob and mysql event

Comment: If you ISP supports mySQL events then let the database do the scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

you can schedule php jobs using [cron](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference/) (if you're in a windows environment you need its internal scheduler) and mysql jobs with the internal [mysql events scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible to do it. Check "Cron-jobs" every normal Linux server got one of that. You can tell him to run something at specific time every day.

Answer (score 0):

USE cron on Linux like this:

```
crontab -e
```

add:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script/script.php
```